# Psychophysiological indicators of relationship/collaboration/alignment

Tags: social-psychology, physiology

I'm working on a question about whether psychophysiological data--[EDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrodermal_activity), [EEG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroencephalography), [pupillometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pupillometry), [HRV/IBI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heart_rate_variability), etc--can indicate within-group (non-romantic!) relationships or collaboration.  My own background is in psychophysiology and neurophysiology, so I'm very comfortable with those kinds of data, but I don't have much experience with groups and relationships.

**What work has been done in assessing social/relationship factors with psychophysiological data?**